# Stored Procedure to search with a wild card

Tags: mysql, search, stored-procedures, wildcard

The following stored procedure returns nothing when executed! Have i made it right?

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_search`(IN `_search` VARCHAR(60))
    BEGIN 
        SELECT `result`
        FROM `search_results` 
        WHERE `keyword` 
        LIKE '%_search%'; 
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `concat()`:

```
    WHERE `keyword` LIKE CONCAT('%', _search, '%')
```

MySQL does not substitute variables in strings.